# Applescript behaves differently when compiled

Tags: applescript

This chunk of Applescript:

```
on collectionToJson(_collection)
  tell application "Capture One 22" to return "{\"name\": " & "\"" & name of _collection & "\", \"id\": " & id of _collection & ", \"kind\": " & "\"" & kind of _collection & "\", \"user\": " & user of _collection & "}"
end collectionToJson
```

behaves differently when run interpreted and compiled. Output in interpreted mode:

```
> osascript target/classes/Collections.applescript --byId 14659
{"name": "StoppingDown", "id": 14659, "kind": "project", "user": true}
```

Output in compiled mode:

```
> osascript target/classes/Collections.scpt --byId 14659
{"name": "StoppingDown", "id": 14659, "kind": "«constant ****CCpj»", "user": true}
```

The 'kind' property (which is an enum) is output in a different way. Does it depend on my scarce knowledge of Applescript or on the specific application I'm talking to?

Full script:

```
on run (_args)
    tell front document of application "Capture One 22"
        set _command to item 1 of _args
        
        if _command is "--byId" then
            set _collection to my findCollectionByIdPath(_args)
            my collectionToJson(_collection)
            
        else if _command is "--byName" then
            set _collection to collection named (item 2 of _args)
            
            repeat with _i from 3 to count of _args
                tell _collection to set _collection to collection named (item _i of _args)
            end repeat
            
            my collectionToJson(_collection)
            
        else if _command is "--children" then
            set _collection to my findCollectionByIdPath(_args)
            tell _collection to my collectionsToJson(collections)
            
        else if _command is "--variants" then
            set _collection to my findCollectionByIdPath(_args)
            tell _collection to my variantsToJson(variants)
        else
            log "Unknown command: " & _command
        end if
    end tell
end run

on findCollectionByIdPath(_args)
    tell front document of application "Capture One 22"
        set _collection to first collection whose its id is item 2 of _args
        
        repeat with _i from 3 to count of _args
            tell _collection to set _collection to (first collection whose its id is (item _i of _args))
        end repeat
        
        return _collection
    end tell
end findCollectionByIdPath

on collectionsToJson(_collections)
    set _result to "["
    set _separator to ""
    repeat with _collection in _collections
        set _result to _result & _separator & my collectionToJson(_collection)
        set _separator to ","
    end repeat
    return _result & "]"
end collectionsToJson

on collectionToJson(_collection)
    tell application "Capture One 22" to return "{\"name\": " & "\"" & name of _collection & "\", \"id\": \"" & id of _collection & "\", \"kind\": " & "\"" & kind of _collection & "\", \"user\": " & user of _collection & "}"
end collectionToJson

on variantsToJson(_variants)
    set _result to "["
    set _separator to ""
    repeat with _variant in _variants
        set _result to _result & _separator & my variantToJson(_variant)
        set _separator to ","
    end repeat
    return _result & "]"
end variantsToJson

on variantToJson(_variant)
    -- FIXME: it seems that this 'tell' slows down a lot
    tell application "Capture One 22" to return ("{\"name\": \"" & (name of _variant) as text) & "\", \"id\": \"" & id of _variant & "\", \"rating\": " & rating of _variant & ", \"colorTag\": " & color tag of _variant & "}"
end variantToJson
```

Comment: Where does the argument to the handler come from in either case?

Comment: It depends on if the particular scripting dictionary has been loaded (or exists).  The stuff enclosed in chevrons is just the raw event code.

Comment: I've added the whole script listing.

Comment: Yes, I understand there's something related to the dictionary — but why does it work if I don't compile the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is normal and to be expected. AppleScript only loads application dictionaries when compiling and decompiling a script. It doesn’t load the dictionary when executing a compiled script because it doesn’t need it.

A compiled script stores application-defined keywords as “four-char codes”, e.g. the keyword `project` maps to the code `CCpj`, which AppleScript displays as `«constant ****CCpj»` when the dictionary definition isn’t available.

While AS can be “forced” to load an application’s dictionary even when it’s not needed (using the `run script` command to compile a trivial script targeting that application), the obvious straightforward solution is to translate keywords to strings yourself:

```
to formatKind(aKind)
  if aKind is project then
    return "project"
  else if ...
    ...
  else
    return aKind as string
  end
end formatKind
```

Or, in your particular case, since you’re running the script via `osascript`, just keep using the uncompiled form: unlike early System 7 days, where compiling took an appreciable length of time, modern machines are fast enough that it really doesn’t make a noticeable difference to running time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, in particular for the last sentence that answers the next question I was going to ask.